# Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getAlbumTable

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I am trying to modify and copy a custom module i have setup everything DB connection is but getting the error while going to view my module as follows:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getAlbumTable
```

Here is the my module.config file:

```
return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
     ),
 ),


 // The following section is new and should be added to your file
 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'album' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

 'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
);
```

And here is the database connection in global.php

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=stickynotes;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),

'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
);
```

**Here is the code from the module.php for the services config:**

```
 public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
```

**Here is the controller to get the album:**

```
   <?php 

   namespace Album\Controller;

   use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
   use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


   class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
    {
     protected $_albumTable;

     public function indexAction()

      {
         return new ViewModel(array(

         'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),

     ));         
      }

    }

    ?>
```

Here is the attachment for the database tables:
[Database tables View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Owu2.png)

Can anyone please let me know where i have to debug this error and fix the problem?

Comment: Seems like all of the code we need is not there. Where are the service_manager configuration for the tables? How do you inject your table in your controller? (Here you have an invokable, not a factory, so you can't inject...). Are you using ZF3 or ZF2?

Comment: its zf2. what part of the code you want to see so i will update the question @Thomas Dutrion

Comment: That would mainly be any `service_manager` key in your config files, along with any `->get(` anywhere in your code (should be in factories mainly).

Comment: Show where and how do you call `getAlbumTable`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have Just Solved it by adding the Services in my Module file Module.php now the it is working fine:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$this->getAlbumTable()` Zend looks for controller plugin, but there is none plugin with such name, so it throws exception.

If you want access any class from `service_manager` you have to inject it through factory.

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyNamespace\Controller\AlbumController;

class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param null|array $options
     * @return AlbumController
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : AlbumController::class;
        $albumTable = $container->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable'); // get service from service manager
        $controller = new $class($albumTable);

        return $controller;

    }
    /**
     * Provided for backwards compatibility; proxies to __invoke().
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface|ServiceLocatorInterface $container
     * @return AlbumController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
    {
        return $this($container, AlbumController::class);
    }
}
```

In `module.config.php`

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
    ),
),
```

In your controller:

```
   namespace Album\Controller;

   use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
   use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{

     protected $_albumTable;

     public function __construct(AlbumTable $albumTable)
     {
         $this->_albumTable = $albumTable;
     }

     public function indexAction()
     {
         return new ViewModel(array(
             'albums' => $this->_albumTable->fetchAll()

          ));         
     }
}
```

Simple, isn't it? :)

Comment: Where the First part of the code will fall , means which file of my module? @SzymonM

Comment: This line is throwing an error and don't let the code run,
   $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : AlbumController::class;

Comment: Giving me this error:

Controller:
    Album\Controller\Album(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Album\Controller\Album)

Comment: In `module.config.php` in `routes` change `controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album` to `controller => Controller\AlbumController::class`

Comment: While attempting to create controlleralbumcontroller(alias: Controller\AlbumController) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type. :What is this error @SzymonM